# Access MS Build Parameter within a project

Tags: c#, build, msbuild

I have a project within a solution, and a MS Build that builds the solution. As a part of the build, I can add MS Build arguments. Is there anyway that I can reference that build argument within my code inside the project?

Comment: you can conditional compilation symbols in the code.

Comment: @Agalo what would that look like?

Comment: check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A sort of "quick and dirty" way I've achieved this before is by dynamically generating a source file in MSBuild and adding it to the `Compile` item group.

This is assuming you mean MSBuild Properties by "MS Build Parameter(s)", specified like `/p:MyProperty=foo` on the command-line.

```
<Target Name="WriteToFile" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_Lines Include='// auto-generated!' />
    <_Lines Include='public class MyProperties {' />
    <_Lines Include='  public string Property1="$(Property1)"'; />
    <_Lines Include='}'; />
  </ItemGroup>
  <WriteLinesToFile
    File="autogen.cs"
    Lines="@(_Lines)"
    Overwrite="true" />
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="autogen.cs">
  </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```